# Extract month and year from mysql date format

Tags: php, mysql

I have a lot of dates stored in the database like so:

2017-06-01

And there are different months worth of data in the database. I want to show this in a dropdown menu so that a user would see:

April 2017
May 2017
June 2017

I tried this in a while loop as a start to try get the month alone:

`$month = date('F', strtotime($row['b_date']));`

but it just shows January 7 times.

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT 'b_date' FROM `summary`");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $numRows = $result->num_rows;
    if($numRows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $month = date('F', strtotime($row['b_date']));
            echo "<option value=''>{$month}</option>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: hard to say without seeing the code for this and the schema. At best, DISTINCT/GROUP BY?

Comment: @Fred-ii- just edited the question to show the sql

Comment: Don't use quotes `'b_date'`

Comment: @AbraCadaver, those are note quotes

Comment: @Fred-ii- no. I am using ``, not ''

Comment: Yes they are.  You have backticks around `summary` and quotes around `b_date`

Comment: What are the contents of `$row`, what happens when you print it

Comment: @AbraCadaver, apologies. You are correct. For some reason I have done that by accident!

Comment: But now I get the correct months, it is showing multiple of the same month, like April x 7

Comment: I believe we should clear up some of the comments except the first one, which should answer this; somewhat and keep Jeremy's also.

Comment: I have tried using DISTINCT in my sql query and GROUP BY but it still shows the same month multiple times

Comment: can you edit your question with the values and the schema? it's hard to say here. You could try a `WHERE` clause also.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the values are just dates like 2017-04-01, 2017-04-02, 2017-04-03 etc. and that database column is set to DATE

Comment: the manual on php's date http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php shows `F` as being *"A full textual representation of a month, such as January or March"* - yet your `2017-06-01` may be at fault; this TBH is a bit tricky for me and can't put my finger on it.

Comment: you should use mysql DATE_FORMAT()  function to get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this in your query

```
SELECT b_date 
FROM summary
GROUP BY YEAR(b_date), MONTH(b_date)
```

Similar to this issue [SQL group dates by month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107562/sql-group-dates-by-month). My guess would be you are using MySQL, here are the [docs for date manipulation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Better group by year first.

Comment: @Don't Panic Good call

Comment: Glad to hear it